# Good books or material for starting in physics with a high school education?

Tags: entropy, resource-recommendations, education

What are some good entry points into physics? I'm wanting to eventually be able to understand some more abstract concepts like quantum physics but understand that is a very long way away. Just been spending far too long trying to understand things above my pay grade. I'm pretty sure I remember linear algebra being something I should read up on, what are some good books on that subject? What are some other good books that would be entry points? I'm wanting to eventually be able to understand some things like Planck area and a lot of concepts related to entropy. I would consider myself intelligent but not well read as I've slacked on learning since high school. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/2451

Comment: Watch [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mechanical_Universe)